# How can I replace every instance of a pattern in ruby?

Tags: ruby, regex, string, replace

`string.sub` looks like it only replaces the first instance. Is there an option for that or another method that can replace all patterns? Can you do it inside a regex like perl?

(I think something like r/blah/blah/)

... and +1 to anyone who can tell me WHY ON EARTH does `string.sub` replace just the FIRST match?

Comment: For the same reason that Perl needs a `g` modifier to make substitutions global. Replace all is often what you want, but not always.

Answer (score 82, accepted):

[String.gsub](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/String.html#method-i-gsub) should do the trick.

Quoting docs:

> `gsub(pattern, replacement) → new_str`
>
> Returns a copy of str with the **all** occurrences of pattern
>   substituted for the second argument. The pattern is typically a
>   Regexp; if given as a String, any regular expression metacharacters it
>   contains will be interpreted literally, e.g. `\\d` will match a
>   backlash followed by `d`, instead of a digit.

Comment: w00t. Thanks. You would think that sub would do that as a default and then have an int param for replace the first N occurrences!

Comment: DJ: no you wouldn't. If you want to replace the first match, then **SUB**stitute is your choice, if not **G**lobal **SUB**stitute is your choice.

Comment: For further reference, here is the [manual page](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/String.html#method-i-gsub).

Answer (score 8):

I could explain why `sub` just replaces the first match of a pattern, but I think the documentation does it so much better (from `ri String#sub` on the command line):

```
str.sub(pattern, replacement)         => new_str
str.sub(pattern) {|match| block }     => new_str

Returns a copy of _str_ with the _first_ occurrence of _pattern_
replaced with either _replacement_ or the value of the block.
```

Comment: wow, i've been using ruby and rails for years. Today was the 1st time I typed ri something#method because of your post. I had no idea that feature was there! Been just googling the terms and find the docs that way.